# AngularJS ng-map set view position as rectangle coordinates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

Do U know how can I i ng-map directive set position of ng-map view not as center="[40.74, -74.18]", but as rectangle - corner values of map view where i have 4 values [north, south, east, west]?

now i have something like that:

```
<ng-map zoom="11" center="[40.74, -74.18]" class="csiMap" default-style="false"></ng-map>
```

But I want rectangle, not center

Greetings
rizon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fitBounds` function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) is used to set the viewport to contain the given bounds, below is demonstrated how to utilize it with `ng-map` library.

**Example**

```js
angular.module('mapApp', ['ngMap'])
  .controller('mapController', function ($scope, NgMap) {

    NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
      $scope.map = map;
      $scope.bounds = [47.0, 30.0, -80.0, -110.0];


      var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.bounds[1], $scope.bounds[3]);
      var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.bounds[0], $scope.bounds[2]);
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapController">
    <ng-map zoom="4">
    </ng-map>
</div>
```